# RESTFul links / sharing a Rails view on Twitter, Facebook, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app I want to allow the users to share specific views ( generated HTML of their data ) on Twitter or facebook.

Am looking for a logical design flow of what I'd need to do, and links to approved patterns from the social media vendors mentioned.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You question is quite vague. Nevertheless, you cannot really post HTML code to Twitter or FB. Twitter only accepts 140 characters, if you want to "tweet". So, basically, you might want to create a shorten URL for your view on your web application and tweet the URL to the Twitter feed. When a user clicks on it, they will get to see your page. The same goes for FB as well. I hope this makes sense.